# Goutte - array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Tags: php

I am using `PHP 7.1.33` and `"fabpot/goutte": "^3.2"`.

When running the below script I get the following:

```
PHP Warning:  array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\Users\testFile.php on line 88
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\Users\testFile.php:0
PHP   2. updateCalendarDetailsData() C:\Users\testFile.php:104
PHP   3. Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler->each($closure = *uninitialized*) C:\Users\testFile.php:99
PHP   4. {closure:C:\Users\testFile.php:31-99}($node = *uninitialized*, *uninitialized*) C:\Users\Desktop\Code\vendor\symfony\dom-crawler\Crawler.php
:368
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler->each($closure = *uninitialized*) C:\Users\testFile.php:90
PHP   6. {closure:C:\Users\testFile.php:53-90}($LEFT_TD = *uninitialized*, *uninitialized*) C:\Users\Desktop\Code\vendor\symfony\dom-crawler\Crawler.
php:368
PHP   7. array_push(*uninitialized*, *uninitialized*) C:\Users\testFile.php:88
```

I am running the following script:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Goutte\Client;
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

function updateCalendarDetailsData()
{
    $client = new Client();

    $x = 1;
    $LIMIT = 3;
    global $x;
    global $LIMIT;
    $x++;
    $res1Array = array();

    $ffUrlArr = ["https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar.php?month=Jan2020"];
    foreach ($ffUrlArr as $key => $v) {

        try {
            $crawler = $client->request('GET', $ffUrlArr[$key]);
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            error_log($ex);
        }

        $TEMP = array();

        $count = $crawler->filter('.calendar_row')->count();
        $i = 1; // count starts at 1
        $crawler->filter('.calendar_row')->each(function ($node) use ($count, $i) {
            $EVENT = array();
            global $res1Array;

            $EVENTID = $node->attr('data-eventid');

            $API_RESPONSE = file_get_contents('https://www.forexfactory.com/flex.php?do=ajax&contentType=Content&flex=calendar_mainCal&details=' . $EVENTID);

            $API_RESPONSE = str_replace("<![CDATA[", "", $API_RESPONSE);
            $API_RESPONSE = str_replace("]]>", "", $API_RESPONSE);

            $html = <<<HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
       $API_RESPONSE
    </body>
</html>
HTML;

            $subcrawler = new Crawler($html);

            $subcrawler->filter('.calendarspecs__spec')->each(function ($LEFT_TD) {
                global $res1Array;
                global $TEMP;
                global $EVENT;

                $LEFT_TD_INNER_TEXT = trim($LEFT_TD->text());

                if ($LEFT_TD_INNER_TEXT == "Source") {

                    $TEMP = array();
                    $LEFT_TD->nextAll()->filter('a')->each(function ($LINK) {
                        global $TEMP;
                        array_push($TEMP, $LINK->text(), $LINK->attr('href'));
                    });

                    $EVENT['sourceTEXT'] = $TEMP[0];
                    $EVENT['sourceURL'] = $TEMP[1];
                    $EVENT['latestURL'] = $TEMP[3];
                }

                if ($LEFT_TD_INNER_TEXT == "Measures") {
                    $EVENT['measures'] = $LEFT_TD->nextAll()->text();
                }

                if ($LEFT_TD_INNER_TEXT == "Usual Effect") {
                    $EVENT['usual_effect'] = $LEFT_TD->nextAll()->text();
                }

                if ($LEFT_TD_INNER_TEXT == "Derived Via") {
                    $EVENT['derived_via'] = $LEFT_TD->nextAll()->text();
                    var_dump($EVENT);
                    print_r($EVENT);
                    if (empty($EVENT)) {
                        echo "test";
                    }
                    array_push($res1Array, $EVENT); // <---- HERE I GET THE ERROR!
                }
            });
            $i++;
            if ($i > $count) {
                echo "<pre>";
                var_dump($res1Array);
                print_r($res1Array);
                echo "</pre>";
                exit;
            }
        });
    }
    return $res1Array;
}

updateCalendarDetailsData();
```

Any suggestions why I get the warning?

Appreciate your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `global $res1Array` at the top of the `updateCalendarDetailsData()` function. The anonymous callback functions are trying to use this global variable, but you're initializing the local variable, not the global variable. You seem to be assuming that `global` simply allows you to access variables from any outer scope, but it's just for global variables.

You have similar problems with `$TEMP` and `$EVENT`.

A better method is to include the variables in the `use()` list of the functions. Since you're modifying the variables with `array_push()`, you need to declare them as references with `&`.

```
<?php
function updateCalendarDetailsData()
{
    $client = new Client();

    $x = 1;
    $LIMIT = 3;
    global $x;
    global $LIMIT;
    $x++;
    $res1Array = array();

    $ffUrlArr = ["https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar.php?month=Jan2020"];
    foreach ($ffUrlArr as $key => $v) {

        try {
            $crawler = $client->request('GET', $ffUrlArr[$key]);
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            error_log($ex);
        }

        $TEMP = array();

        $count = $crawler->filter('.calendar_row')->count();
        $i = 1; // count starts at 1
        $crawler->filter('.calendar_row')->each(function ($node) use ($count, $i, &$res1Array) {
            $EVENT = array();

            $EVENTID = $node->attr('data-eventid');

            $API_RESPONSE = file_get_contents('https://www.forexfactory.com/flex.php?do=ajax&contentType=Content&flex=calendar_mainCal&details=' . $EVENTID);

            $API_RESPONSE = str_replace("<![CDATA[", "", $API_RESPONSE);
            $API_RESPONSE = str_replace("]]>", "", $API_RESPONSE);

            $html = <<<HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
       $API_RESPONSE
    </body>
</html>
HTML;

            $subcrawler = new Crawler($html);

            $subcrawler->filter('.calendarspecs__spec')->each(function ($LEFT_TD) use (&$res1Array, &$TEMP, &$EVENT) {

                $LEFT_TD_INNER_TEXT = trim($LEFT_TD->text());

                if ($LEFT_TD_INNER_TEXT == "Source") {

                    $TEMP = array();
                    $LEFT_TD->nextAll()->filter('a')->each(function ($LINK) use (&$TEMP) {
                        array_push($TEMP, $LINK->text(), $LINK->attr('href'));
                    });

                    $EVENT['sourceTEXT'] = $TEMP[0];
                    $EVENT['sourceURL'] = $TEMP[1];
                    $EVENT['latestURL'] = $TEMP[3];
                }

                if ($LEFT_TD_INNER_TEXT == "Measures") {
                    $EVENT['measures'] = $LEFT_TD->nextAll()->text();
                }

                if ($LEFT_TD_INNER_TEXT == "Usual Effect") {
                    $EVENT['usual_effect'] = $LEFT_TD->nextAll()->text();
                }

                if ($LEFT_TD_INNER_TEXT == "Derived Via") {
                    $EVENT['derived_via'] = $LEFT_TD->nextAll()->text();
                    var_dump($EVENT);
                    print_r($EVENT);
                    if (empty($EVENT)) {
                        echo "test";
                    }
                    array_push($res1Array, $EVENT); // <---- HERE I GET THE ERROR!
                }
            });
            $i++;
            if ($i > $count) {
                echo "<pre>";
                var_dump($res1Array);
                print_r($res1Array);
                echo "</pre>";
                exit;
            }
        });
    }
    return $res1Array;
}
```